# Get select box name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have couple of select box and I would like to know which select box is triggered.

Html code:

```
<form id="property-filters" method="post">
    <select name="sel1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="sel2">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#property-filters input, #property-filters select', function () 
{
//Get the name of the select box.
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check `this.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the name property of the event fired dom object.

```
$(document).on('change', '#property-filters input, #property-filters select',function () {
   if(this.name == 'sel1'){
       // do the rest
   }else if(this.name == 'sel2'){
       // do the rest    
   }
})
```

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr()`

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('#property-filters select').change(function () {
   alert($(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Check [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrhtssx8/)